# node express calling another REST api on another node express

Tags: node.js, ajax, rest, amazon-web-services, nginx

I have a node-express UI Server to serve reactjs. It calls another node-express server using REST API on port 3001. It all worked fine on my local development machine using http://localhost:3001/.

When I moved it to Amazon aws it wouldn't run unless I opened port 3001 to internet, which I do not want to do. I am using nginx to listen on port 80 and transfer to 3000 for the UI server which then makes API call. I get net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error. I have tested my API server using curl and it all works fine.

I suspect it has something to do with the headers sent with the ajax calls, but don't know where to look. Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a security group for the REST server which only allows a connection on port 3001 from the IP of your node-express UI server. This will allow your REST server to only allow connections from your UI server. [Here's a link to Amazon's Security Group reference docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html)